# django urlconf cant find directives to including urls

Tags: django, django-generic-views, urlconf

i read the "practical django projects" and i stack on chapter 5. In general i have done exactly as it is in the book. I created a urls dir in coltrane app, I removed the urls.py file and i edited the urls.py in cms to write the include statements for each coltranes' model. But the server returns with an **ImproperlyConfigured** type error and a message that says "The included urlconf cms.urls doesn't have any patterns in it". i thought that it should search into coltrane.urls so i set the urlconf to this one. But the output still is the same. [here](https://github.com/b10n1k/cms) is the code.

Can anyone show me why this is happen or give me some good resources or example to understand how it works???

Answer (score 1):

Your `ROOT_URLCONF` is coltrane.urls, which is a python package. Which means the __init__.py will be used. But there is no urlpatterns variable in your __init__.py. If you want to include all the sub-url files you could do something like the following:

```
import categories
import entries
import links
import tags

urlpatterns = categories.urlpatterns + entries.urlpatterns + links.urlpatterns + tags.urlpatterns
```

However, I would not necessarily suggest that. Also, coltrane.urls doesn't look like a root url file to me. Maybe cms.urls should be the root. Then in cms.urls you can include coltrane.urls by adding this to your urlpatterns:

```
(r'', include('coltrane.urls')),
```